# JSF: CSS file as byte[] to String

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have a .css file saved id DB as byte[]. Now i need to include content of that file in a page body. I do it in this way:

```
class FlowUtils {
    private Integer themeId;
    private ThemeDAO themeDAO;

    public String getThemeCss() {
        byte[] b = themeDAO.get(themeId).getCss();
        return new String(b);
    }
}

<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #{flowUtils.themeCss}
    </style>
</h:head>
```

Is this sufficient and safe way ?

Comment: Looks good to me. Why would you think this is not good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return new String(b);
```

This way you're dependent on the server machine default character encoding which may not be the right character encoding per se. Imagine that the `byte[]` contains UTF-8 bytes and the server machine is configured to use ISO-8859-1 as default encoding, then the `new String(b)` may possibly return [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). You'd like to specify the character encoding explicitly.

```
return new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

As to the approach, I would recommend using a servlet which returns a fullworthy `.css` file above putting the styles raw in `<style>`. This way you end up with a smaller page (in terms of bytes) and you can control the caching of the returned CSS file so that you don't necessarily need to return it on *every* request. This is finally more efficient in terms of network bandwidth consumption and server CPU/memory resources.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssservlet?id=123" />
```

where the file servlet does something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = themeDAO.get(request.getParameter("id"));
response.setContentType("text/css;charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L); // Cache for one week.
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

To improve it more, let it return `InputStream` instead of `byte[]` so that's a tad more memory efficient (a `byte[]` is kept *entirely* in memory while an `InputStream` is just a pointer). Then write it to `OutputStream` the usual Java IO way with a little byte buffer.

#### See also:

- [Example of a file servlet supporting resumes, caching and GZIP](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)
- [Webapplication performance tips and tricks](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html)

Comment: You are always the best :) Thanks.

Comment: Do You have idea how to connect servlet that You propose to h:inputTextarea for editing css code ?

Comment: That's a story apart. Just assign it as a string bean property (with the correct encoding!).